# MySQL query to join two tables with similar data

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL tables that look like this:

questions_table:

```
questionID, question, optionID, optionText
   '1',    'question1', 100,   'option1',
   '2',    'question2', 200,   'option2',
   '3',    'question3', 300,   'option3',
   '3',    'question3', 400,   'option4',
   '3',    'question3', 500,   'option5',
   '4',    'question4', 600,   'option6'
```

answers_table:

```
questionID answeredOptionID
   '1'      '100'      
   '2'      '200'
   '3'      '400'
   '4'      '600'
```

And I need to join these two table like this:

```
questionID, question, optionID, optionText answeredOptionID
   '1',    'question1', 100,   'option1',        '100'
   '2',    'question2', 200,   'option2',        '200'
   '3',    'question3', 300,   'option3',         Null
   '3',    'question3', 400,   'option4',        '400'
   '3',    'question3', 500,   'option5',         Null
   '4',    'question4', 600,   'option6'         '600'
```

Please, help me with the query. Simple JOIN or LEFT, RIGHT JOIN don't work - I get duplicates of answers instead Nulls where I needed

Comment: LEFT JOIN should be the right way

Comment: Post the query you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a left join on questionID and optionID

```
select a.questionID, a.question, a.optionID, a.optionText, b.answeredOptionID 
from questions_table a 
left join  answers_table b on a.questionID = b.questionID 
         and a.optionID = b.answeredOptionID 
ORDER BY questTbl.optionID
```

and for checked  or not checked

```
select a.questionID, a.question, a.optionID, a.optionText, 
 case when b.answeredOptionID is not null then'Checked' ELSE 'Not checked' END result 
from questions_table a 
left join  answers_table b on a.questionID = b.questionID 
         and a.optionID = b.answeredOptionID 
ORDER BY questTbl.optionID
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer looks like almost the same as previous, just without the 'order by' command, so I mark the previous as the right one. Anyway, do you know how to put some text instead of the results? In this case if the answeredOptionID is not null, it is 'checked' and if not, then 'not checked'?

Comment: @ArturTakoev  ... strange for right answer posted  at least an hour before the others that is not checked  as accepted for an order by  ..  anyway  .. order by added . and manage for .  answeredOptionID  added  too ...  ..

Comment: oh, sorry for that, there is no exact time of the post and I thought that the lower in the list is the later. I've checked your answer as right.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for your problem:

```
SELECT questTbl.questionID, questTbl.question, questTbl.optionID,
questTbl.optionText, ansTbl.answeredOptionID 
FROM questions_table questTbl 
LEFT JOIN answers_table ansTbl 
ON questTbl.questionID = ansTbl.questionID
AND questTbl.optionID= ansTbl.answeredOptionID
ORDER BY questTbl.optionID
```

For Demo, follow this link:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd09e0/5

Answer (score 0):

```
select questions_table.questionid,questions_table.question,optionid,
questions_table.optiontext,answers_table.answeredOptionID
from questions_table inner join answers_table
on questions_table.questionID=answers_table.questionID
```

Check-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd09e0/10

Comment: The query gives me the duplicates in answeredOptionID